# Weird input from keyboard using USB to PS/2 adapter/converter

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, adapter, ps2-keyboard

I recently purchased a USB to PS/2 "converter adapter" that was advertised to need no drivers and just "plug and play." I have tested it with at least 5 different PS/2 keyboards and 2 different computers (both on Windows 7, which the adapter should support), but I get the same problem: **all the keys are mapped wrong.**
For example, the "4 , 5 , 6" buttons on the number pad all print "4." The "P" key is "Caps Lock", etc.

My question is this: **what am I doing wrong? Do I need a driver? Have I been scammed?** **I have looked all over Google, but I couldn't find anyone else with this problem.** Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: Just wanted to clarify, I'm connecting PS/2 keyboards to USB ports.

Comment: Can you be more specific. Are you trying to convert a PS/2 keyboard to a USB computer? Or vice-versa. And while I'm sure someone can help you, why would you be trying to use a PS/2 keyboard? New USB keyboards are a dime a dozen. This leads me to believe there is something special about these keyboards, and maybe that's why you're having trouble.

Comment: @Appleoddity The reason I want to do this is because I have a huge load of older mechanical keyboards that I would like to use which are a lot higher quality than today's keyboards. They are standard brands like Dell, Compaq, HP, etc.